# User Titles in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I am importing a JSON file of (Example) Users into Realtime Database and have noticed a slight issue.

When added, each User is sorted by the number order they are in on the JSON File. Since it starts with User 4, it has the value of 1. As seen here:

[image: Here].

The User Json is formatted as such:

```
{
    "instagram": "null",
    "invited_by_user_profile": "null",
    "name": "Rohan Seth",
    "num_followers": 4187268,
    "num_following": 599,
    "photo_url": "https://clubhouseprod.s3.amazonaws.com:443/4_b471abef-7c14-43af-999a-6ecd1dd1709c",
    "time_created": "2020-03-17T07:51:28.085566+00:00",
    "twitter": "rohanseth",
    "user_id": 4,
    "username": "rohan"
}
```

Is there some easy way to make it so the titles in Firebase are the User ID's of each user instead of the numbers currently used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a JSON into the Firebase Realtime Database, it uses whatever keys exist in the JSON. There is no support to remap the keys during the import.

But of course you can do this with some code:

- For example, you can change the JSON before you import it, to have the keys you want.
- You can read the JSON in a small script, and then insert the data into Firebase through its API.

I'd recommend against using sequential numeric IDs as keys though. To learn why, have a look at this blog post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)..

Comment: To add onto Frank's answer here with an example of extracting the IDs out of an array ready for upload, you can achieve it with JavaScript using just `arrayOfUserData.reduce((acc, userData) => (acc[userData.uid] = userData, acc), {})` (however for 90k entries, JS might choke with this strategy).

Comment: In a similar vein, to assign push IDs to your data structure, you could use the RTDB push key generator: `const rootRef = ref(getDatabase()); const getId = () => push(rootRef).key;`. However, because RTDB push IDs are based off your system clock, you could use Firestore's ID generator instead for more randomness using `const colRef = collection(getFirestore(), "404"); const getId = () => doc(colRef).id;`. Both could be applied using `arrayOfUserData.reduce((acc, userData) => (acc[getId()] = userData, acc), {})`